# How do I extend a class thats using direct injection

Tags: typescript, angular, extending

Hopefully this should be a relatively easy question for some of you out there...

I am trying to extend a component but I am not sure how to deal with the constructor method of the new component.

Below is my Base component

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ControlsService }    from '../controls.service'

@Component({
  moduleId      : module.id,
  selector      : 'app-base',
  templateUrl   : 'base.component.html',
  styleUrls     : ['base.component.css'],
  providers     : [ControlsService]
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(_controlService:ControlsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

     // console.log(this._controlService.getControlByID('B5EE385D-1D6A-335A-1E94-2F857428A6FB'))  

  }

}
```

And Below is my new component

```
import { Component, OnInit }        from '@angular/core';
import { MdToolbar }                from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
import { MdIcon, MdIconRegistry}    from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { PanelComponent }           from '../panel/panel.component'
import { BaseComponent }            from '../base/base.component'
import { ControlsService }          from '../controls.service'

@Component({
  moduleId      : module.id,
  selector      : 'app-workbench',
  templateUrl   : 'workbench.component.html',
  styleUrls     : ['workbench.component.css'],
  directives    : [MdToolbar,MdIcon,PanelComponent],
  providers     : [MdIconRegistrym,ControlsService]
})
export class WorkbenchComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit{

  workbenchTitle = "Selection Category "

  constructor(_controlService:ControlsService) 
  {
      super(this._controlService)
  }

  ngOnInit() {



  }


}
```

I need my _controlService to be in the base component as this service will retrieve the controls parameters, but it seems that if I create the service in the base components constructor method, I then have to pass it into the base component from the new component.  I would prefer not to do this but it seems I may have to.

The Error that is being returned to me is:
(17, 21): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to properly extend this base component.

Thanks!

Comment: What position is `(17, 21)`?

Comment: thats the super(this._controlService) part in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.` is invalid

```
export class WorkbenchComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(_controlService:ControlsService) 
  {
      // super(this._controlService)
      // should be
      super(_controlService)
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Same error? I guess it is a "known" issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9758

Comment: Same error Gunter - thanks for looking and pointing me to that link... It seems crazy that you cant extend a class that uses direct injection!!

Comment: Hi Gunter,   I went back and had a fresh look at this problem today and it seems that your answer was correct - so thank you!